# Can I do this part of code shorter and cleaner? How?

Tags: apex, soql, algorithm

Help me please: I want to make this part of code shorter. Maybe with a few methods. But I don't know how to do that with using SOQL. To many double-parts are here.

```
public List<Item__c> serchItem(){
    if(String.isNotBlank(nameSearchField) && String.isBlank(statusSearchField)){
        String filterName = '%'+ nameSearchField +'%';
        itemList = [SELECT Id, Name, Status__c FROM Item__c WHERE Name LIKE : filterName];
    } else if(String.isBlank(nameSearchField) && String.isNotBlank(statusSearchField)){
        itemList = [SELECT Id, Name, Status__c FROM Item__c WHERE Status__c =: statusList];
    } else if(String.isNotBlank(nameSearchField) && String.isNotBlank(statusSearchField)){
        String filterName = '%'+ nameSearchField +'%';
        itemList = [SELECT Id, Name, Status__c FROM Item__c WHERE Name LIKE : filterName AND Status__c =: statusList];
    } else{
        itemList = [SELECT Id, Name, Status__c FROM Item__c];
    }
    return itemList;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, we can use [dynamic SOQL](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dynamic_soql.htm):

```
public List<Item__c> serchItem(){
    String[] filters = new String[0];
    if(String.isNotBlank(nameSearchField)) {
        filters.add('name like \'%' + String.escapeSingleQuotes(nameSearchField)+'%\'');
    }
    if(String.isNotBlank(statusSearchField)) {
        filters.add('status = :statusSearchField');
    }
    return Database.query(
        'select id, name, status__c from item__c'+
        (filters.isEmpty()?'':' WHERE '+String.join(filters,' AND '))
    );
}
```

Here, we generate a list of filters, and if there are any, we modify the query by adding the WHERE clause.